# Webpack 5 doesn't see styles in vue 2 sfc

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, webpack-5, vue-loader

I'm starting a legacy assembly of webpack 3 on webpack 5. When setting up the config and updating plugins, I ran into a problem, the sfc components of vue see only the styles of scss modules.

```html
<!-- it works -->
<style module lang="scss">
    .foo {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<!-- this does not work  -->
<style lang="scss">
.bar {
    color: red;
}
</style>

<!-- this does not work  -->
<style>
.foo-bar {
    color: red;
}
</style>

<!-- this does not work  -->
<style scoped>
.baz {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

The problem is clearly in the loader settings, but I don't know how to fix it.

Сurrent webpack config

```js
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const production = env.prod === 1;

    return {
        devtool: production ? "" : "inline-source-map",
        context: path.resolve(__dirname, "static/src"),
        entry: entry,
        mode: production ? "production" : "development",
        output: {
            filename: "js/[name].js",
            chunkFilename: production
                ? "js/[name].[chunkhash].js"
                : "js/[name].js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static/build/"),
            publicPath: "/static/",
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules\/(?!(swiper|dom7)\/).*/],
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "babel-loader",
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: "vue-loader",
                },
                {
                    test: /\.s?css$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: {
                                modules: {
                                    localIdentName: "[local]__[hash:base64:5]",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "postcss-loader",
                            options: {
                                postcssOptions: {
                                    sourceMap: !production,
                                    plugins: [
                                        "autoprefixer",
                                        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: !production,
                                additionalData: `
                                    @import "./static/src/styles/_mixins.scss";
                                    @import "./static/src/styles/_varaibles.scss";
                                    @import "./static/src/styles/_colors.scss";
                                    `,
                                sassOptions: {
                                    indentedSyntax: false,
                                },
                                implementation: require("sass"),
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /(\.jpg|\.png|\.ico|.gif|\.tif|\.svg|\.webp|\.cur)\??.*$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "file-loader",
                            options: {
                                name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "file-loader",
                            options: {
                                name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /jquery-mousewheel/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "imports-loader",
                        },
                    ],
                },

                {
                    test: /malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "imports-loader",
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                vue$: "vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js",
            },
            extensions: ["*", ".js", ".vue", ".json"],
        },
        plugins: [
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),

            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "css/[name].css",
            }),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        ],
    };
};
```

Current devDependencies

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "import-glob": "^1.5.0",
    "import-glob-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
  }
```

Old webpack config

```js
module.exports = (env, argv) =>  {
    const production = env.prod === 1;

    return {
        devtool: production ? '' : 'inline-source-map',
        context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src'),
        entry: entry,
        output: {
            filename: 'js/[name].js',
            chunkFilename: production ? 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/build/'),
            publicPath: '/static/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules\/(?!(swiper|dom7)\/).*/],
                    use: [
                        'cache-loader',
                        'babel-loader',
                        'eslint-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.vue?$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        loaders: {
                            js: 'cache-loader!babel-loader!eslint-loader',
                            scss: 'cache-loader!vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?data=@import "./static/src/styles/_mixins"; @import "./static/src/styles/_varaibles";',
                        },
                        cssModules: {
                            localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                            camelCase: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: [
                            'cache-loader',
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {sourceMap: !production}
                            },
                            {
                                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                                options: {
                                    sourceMap: !production,
                                    plugins: function () {
                                        return [
                                            require('autoprefixer'),
                                            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes')
                                        ];
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                loader: 'sass-loader',
                                options: {
                                    sourceMap: !production,
                                    data: '@import "./static/src/styles/_mixins";' +
                                        ' @import "./static/src/styles/_varaibles";' +
                                        ' @import "./static/src/styles/_colors"; '
                                },
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /\.сss$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: [
                            'cache-loader',
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {sourceMap: !production}
                            },
                            {
                                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                                options: {
                                    sourceMap: !production,
                                    plugins: function () {
                                        return [
                                            require('autoprefixer'),
                                            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes')
                                        ];
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /(\.jpg|\.png|\.ico|.gif|\.tif|\.svg|\.webp)\??.*$/,
                    use: 'url-loader?limit=1&name=images/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader?limit=1&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {test: /jquery-mousewheel/, loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false&this=>window'},
                {test: /malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/, loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false&this=>window'}
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
            },
            extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
        },
        plugins: [
            // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            //     analyzerMode: !production ? 'server' : 'disabled'
            // }),
            require('autoprefixer'),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                chunks: Object.keys(entry),
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: 'css/[name].css',
                ignoreOrder: true,
                allChunks: true,
            }),
            new styleLintPlugin({
                configFile: 'stylelint.',
                context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src'),
                files: '**/*.scss',
                failOnError: false,
                quiet: false
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                'window.$': 'jquery'
            }),
            // new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            //     host: 'localhost',
            //     port: 8888,
            //     proxy: 'http://commercial.localhost:8000/',
            // }),
        ]
    };
};
```

I tried to rearrange the loader dependencies in different ways in the webpack config, but the styles from vue sfc do not appear everywhere.

Tried to change dependencies of different versions.

UPDATE:

Try digging towards the `oneOf` property in the webpack config.

```js
 {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    oneOf: [
                        {
                            resourceQuery: /module/,
                            use: [
                                {
                                    loader: 'vue-style-loader',
                                },
                                'cache-loader',
                                {
                                    loader: 'css-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false,
                                        importLoaders: 2,
                                        modules: {
                                            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
                                            auto: () => true
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false,
                                        postcssOptions: {
                                            plugins: [
                                                function () { /* omitted long function */ }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        resources: [
                                            path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src/styles/_mixins.scss'),
                                            path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src/styles/_varaibles.scss'),
                                            path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src/styles/_colors.scss'),
                                        ]
                                    },
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            resourceQuery: /\?vue/,
                            use: [
                                {
                                    loader: 'vue-style-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false,
                                        shadowMode: false
                                    }
                                },
                                'cache-loader',
                                {
                                    loader: 'css-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false,
                                        importLoaders: 2
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false,
                                        postcssOptions: {
                                            plugins: [
                                                function () { /* omitted long function */ }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        resources: [
                                            path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src/styles/_mixins.scss'),
                                            path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src/styles/_varaibles.scss'),
                                            path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src/styles/_colors.scss'),
                                        ]
                                    },
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            use: [
                                {
                                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                                },
                                'cache-loader',
                                {
                                    loader: 'css-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false,
                                        importLoaders: 2
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false,
                                        postcssOptions: {
                                            plugins: [
                                                function () { /* omitted long function */ }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        resources: [
                                            path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src/styles/_mixins.scss'),
                                            path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src/styles/_varaibles.scss'),
                                            path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/src/styles/_colors.scss'),
                                        ]
                                    },
                                },
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.сss$/,
                    oneOf: [
                        // it is `<style module>`
                        {
                            resourceQuery: /module/,
                            use: [
                                'vue-style-loader',
                                'cache-loader',
                                {
                                    loader: 'css-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        sourceMap: false,
                                        modules: true,
                                        localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        ],
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'vue-style-loader',
                        },
                        'cache-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: false,
                                modules: true,
                                // localsConvention: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: false,
                                // plugins: function () {
                                //     return [
                                //         require('autoprefixer'),
                                //         require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes')
                                //     ];
                                // }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am facing the same problem ...

Comment: @Batyodie Do u fix this issue? I have same problem.

Comment: @RyanNghiem


Partly. I went from the opposite. Installed a separate vue assembly via vue cli.

Got vue cli build build config vue: 
`
vue inspect > output.js

`

And then I began to study what I was doing wrong. I've already dropped the whole thing. I managed to change jobs :)

Comment: @RyanNghiem i am update question. Check.